# Trying to list the amount of specific years are in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm Trying to select a datetime with a specific year from the table and display the amount of those dates that have that year.

I can select just the year from the datetime, but it gives me the amount of every single specific date, not just the year. Like:

```
|       Date | Amount |
| 2012-04-07 |      5 |
| 2012-05-21 |      5 |
```

but I just want `2012, 10`.

```
Select YEAR(Orderdate), count(*)
From Orders
Group by Orderdate
```

The output needs to show a single row with 2012 in one column, and the total count of 2012's in the second column. Like this:

```
| Year | Amount |
| 2012 |     10 |
| 2013 |      8 |
| 2014 |      2 |
```

Answer (score 3):

Use proper date logic in your `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT YEAR(OrderDate) AS [Year],
       COUNT(OrderID) AS Orders --Assumed Column Name
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate >= '20120101'
  AND OrderDate < '20130101'
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate);
```

A clause like `YEAR(OrderDate)` isn't SARGable, meaning that the indexes in your table can't be used. That could have severe implications on your query's performance. As a result using Boolean logic without applying a function to your column in the `WHERE` is the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server;

```
SELECT YEAR(Orderdate), COUNT(1)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY YEAR(Orderdate)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to count so I didn't even think of putting a 1 in there! :D

Comment: I'm discovering `COUNT(1)` now. Useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221649/3283073).

Comment: @Johwhite . . . `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by writing a nested query

```
SELECT Year , Count(*) AS Total_Count
FROM (Select YEAR(Orderdate) AS Year, *
      From Orders)
WHERE Year = '2012'
GROUP BY Year
```